# Python/Django - not able to run stand alone script / classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with running parts of script in Django as I can't get it to run the classes. The class I would like to import is this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    City = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Province = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I have found some things when I tried to find a solution and at this point I have this:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'portal.portal.settings'
import django
django.setup()
from portal.core.models import *
```

When I run this, it gives an error for `django.setup()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Portal\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Portal\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Portal\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

'core' is the package module where all the functions are located the build up is like this: there is:

- portal > portal > settings
- portal > core

So I thought, maybe the whole directing goes wrong, I'm not sure. I did change it to:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'portal.settings'
```

but then it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'portal.settings'`

Could someone help me to understand what is happening here and how I can really run the models?

Comment: Did you mean to write 'portal.portal.settings' for the os.environ above and then change it down below?

Comment: @AaronCloud yes indeed, I changes the 'portal.portal.settings' to 'portal.settings'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what I did wrong: I thought I could just use the interactive Django version in my python console, but apparently this is not possible :P. So I found out what I actually wanted: to create the interactive shell to run my python scripts of Django in.

in cmd prompt:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and from there just import and run all the functions I want. I really didn't know I couldn't run individual scripts in my python console so that's why I kept getting error messages

EDIT:

I also got it working now in my python console (as now I knew what I was looking for), the things I needed to call before running my Django code was:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append("path/to/djangoapp")
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
from django.conf import settings
import django
django.setup()
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you couldn't run the script alone. Because its having Django Framework's dependency.

Example: Models

Comment: I know... how can I check the models in a python run alone?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay so, please let me know what information I should give more. Because I just started Django and from my view this ( plus the 'from django.db import models') should already work without running any other of my scripts, but apparently not.. What information is handy to have?

Comment: @Karthik Merk : I do set: from django.db import models , so that should be okay then? Or what should I setup more?